# PCA making my image garbage

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn, computer-vision, pca

so I have 42,000 images. Each image is 28x28 so there are 784 features or pixels.

I want to make a handwritten digit classification system.

So I thought I should use PCA in order to reduce the dimension of the images.

Here is the code for PCA

```
pipeline = Pipeline([ ('scaling', StandardScaler()),('pca',PCA(n_components=676))])
X_array = pipeline.fit_transform(X_array)
```

Now the problem is that the PCA is making all images random type, I mean all pixels are completely random in color.

Here is an image of a number before PCA

[image: image of the number zero]

Here is an image of a number after PCA

[image: after PCA here is the same image]

Here is another image reduced by PCA

[image: Here is another image reduced by PCA]

I'm reducing the dimension of the image to 26x26 from 28x28

Why it is happening

Answer (score 3):

Basically, what your PCA code is doing is considering your 28x28 array (you are passing one image at a time, right?) as a dataset of 28 examples of 28 numeric features. That's why the output does not make sense. PCA is a method for reducing the dimensionality of complete datasets, not for zooming out images.

For [PCA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principal_component_analysis) to work properly, you should flatten out all the features of your images (each as an array of 784 features) and feed all of them as a single dataset (that would be a 42000 x 784 matrix). Then, from the output of the method, pick as many columns as necessary so that most of the variance of your dataset is kept (this probably won't be more than 10, 20 features in total).

The output dataset still will look weird when printing out each row as an image, but will have way less features than the original (you should end up with a matrix of size 42000 x 20 roughly, instead of 42000 x 784 - that's why PCA is used as a dimensionality reduction method), and will retain most of its predictive power.

After that, you could just feed the dataset to your favourite classifier in the next step of the pipeline.